# How to create ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic2

i am new to ionic2 and not able to create ionic2 app

if i run this command

it will create ionic3

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

i am getting error if i run this command

```
npm install -g ionic@2.3.0
```

error

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ionic@2.3.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-25T08_11_14_543Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Simmilar question to it
[TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331005/npm-error-no-matching-version-found-for)

Comment: what command should i run  to install all dependencies for ionic2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [a link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-ionic1-and-ionic-angular/90964)! to know the difference between  ionic and ionic-angular and 
to create ionic2 refer this [a link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-can-i-create-ionic2-app/91814)!

Answer (score 1):

`ionic 2.2.3` doesn't exist, after releasing `ionic 2.2.0`, ionic cli version moved to `3.0.0`.

`npm install -g ionic@2.2.0` will work.

And to create ionic 2 project you need to change version of `ionic-angular` in you project, not in `ionic-cli`.

Ionic framework (ionic-angular) and ionic-cli both are different.

[CHANGELOG v2.x.x](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/2.x/CHANGELOG.md).

[CHANGELOG v3.x.x](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: what is the difference between Ionic framework (ionic-angular) and ionic-cli

Comment: can u explain me little bit about both

Comment: you can google it. I hope you got answer of your question.

Comment: how to change version of ionic-angular

Comment: in your projects package.json. but why you want that, 3 is better. I hope you got answers for this question.