# Cannot upgrade to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Vue 2 to Vue 3 following this guide:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html#installation

However I fail at multiple levels

1. When I want to upgrade loader `npm install vue-loader@^16.0.0`

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @vue/babel-preset-app@^4.5.13.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chyno/.npm/_logs/2021-07-25T08_33_22_878Z-debug.log
```

2. When I want to upgrade cli service `vue upgrade`

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @vue/cli-service@~4.5.13.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chyno/.npm/_logs/2021-07-25T08_41_29_627Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error @vue/cli-service@~4.5.13
```

3. When updating package.json according to the guide

```
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.1.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chyno/.npm/_logs/2021-07-25T08_44_50_636Z-debug.log
```

I'm using nvm 0.38.0, node v16.5.0, npm 7.19.1

Comment: Does this question/answer help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331005/npm-error-no-matching-version-found-for/44332468

Comment: All of those outputs from `npm view` suggest that there are available versions that I need. (@vue/babel-preset-app 4.5.13, @vue/vue-cli-service 4.5.13, @vue/compiler-sfc 3.1.5)

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64881079/8172857

Comment: Thanks, but there I fail again at the step 2: "No matching version found for @vue/compiler-dom@3.1.5". Maybe it's something wrong with npm?

Comment: Check this tutorial for Vue v3 setup without vue-cli: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-vue-js-project-from-scratch-without-vue-cli/

Comment: Thanks, I don't remeber how I've solved this particular one, but now I think that in such cases `npm cache clean --force` might help.